# mysql workbench disable definer

Tags: mysql

I've been using mysql in linux since they have the mysql workbench which add speed on development.

It has synchronize method which is good. Now I have three database for a development my own computer, test server, and development server.

Updating table from one server to another is easy using the synchronize method, but for trigger, procedure ( routines ), event and function is like hell.

For above type mysql workbench automatically add "DEFINER" stuff whenever you create or alter it, which of course will be different in each server. And due to that during synchronization, I must edit manually or else it will always be failed. Selecting option "Ignore check definer" also not working.

I don't like using mysqldump because I cannot automatically generate the change, it's problematic to create "ALTER" command every time during development. There is some tool in web, but it introduce new problem than solving one.

For function and routines every time before updating the other server I just login to mysql console and run this

```
update mysql.proc set definer = '' where db = <my db>
```

Then this will update my model in mysql workbench and remove all definer string. But for trigger there is no easy way, and I cannot update INFORMATION_SCHEME.TRIGGERS cause it's only a view like table.

I have 50+ table with 1-2 trigger each. That is a waste of time to edit one by one. And am prefer to use one tool only for all.

Perhaps we can disable this function in mysql workbench ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer if you want to use mysql workbench to ease up development

1. Always use model to create or alter any of your database item, then sync it to every source.
2. Don't write definer = user something but use definer = CURRENT_USER() and let mysql server define it it self.
3. Never sync back from source to model cause it will update the definer using source.

With above method synchronization between mysql instance can be achieve easily